# Get UITextField Y coordinate on UIView level?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, cell, coordinate

Currently I have a UITextField in a custom cell and I want to get the Y coordinate of that UITextField on the level of the View Controller's view (UIView). Currently I am trying to do something like this:

```
if (thetextField.superview.superview.superview.frame.origin.y >= keyboardY) {

}
```

But it seems that the Y coordinate is always 0 when it is in fact not. Is there any way to achieve this?

I am doing this because I want to detect whether the UIKeyboard is blocking the UITextField on the UIView level so that I can re-arrange my cells accordingly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check `convertPoint:*` methods in [UIView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html). These methods allow you to map point to or from other views coordinates.

Provided that `self` is a view controller, this line returns text field's origin in view controller's view coordinates:

```
[thetextField convertPoint:thetextField.frame.origin toView:self.view];
```

You can also convert rects in a similar fashion using `convertRect:*` methods.

Comment: Awesome! btw its frame.origin :)

Comment: For me this is worked..    let originInSuperview:CGPoint =   textField .convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.view)
                    
                    print(originInSuperview)                                                                   This is for swift..

Comment: The one given by narasimha worked for me using xcode 9.3

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 version:

```
thetextField.convert(thetextField.frame.origin, to:self.view)
```

It returns a CGPoint, so you can access "x" or "y" properties.