# How to find the position of UITextField by Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I find the position of `UITextField` by Swift?

I want to know the distance between my `UITextField` and the bottom position of view.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028850/ios-get-location-of-a-view-in-a-window

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to move my textfield up with the correct distance for each off it.

Comment: @VarisDarasirikul  did you try  `autolayout` ?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474160/get-uitextfield-y-coordinate-on-uiview-level

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this,

To get your textfield position in your program.

```
println("Your textfiled position : \(textfiled.frame)") // (x,y,width,height)
```

To get your BottowView position in your program.

```
println("BottomView position : \(bottomview.frame)") // (x,y,width,height)
```

To get Distance between two position.

```
println("Distance x:(textfiled.frame.origin.x - bottomview.frame.origin.x) ")
println("Distance y:(textfiled.frame.origin.y - bottomview.frame.origin.y) ")
println("Distance width:(textfiled.frame.size.width - bottomview.frame.size.width) ")
println("Distance height:(textfiled.frame.size.height - bottomview.frame.size.height) ")
```

Answer (score 2):

In the storyBoard:

Select the UITextField...
Hold Alt (Option) key and move your mouse pointer.
You will see red lines indicating the distance to whatever you are pointing at.